# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x92

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am getting a JSON message from windows client to my rest endpoint backend. Even before this JSON message is reached to my REST endpoint, an error is thrown while parsing this message.

I have asked API caller to add the `"Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` , in the header, but still I am getting the below mentioned error, Could somebody kindly help me to understand how to overcome this issue.

```
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 625] (through reference chain: sg.butterfly.emenu.api.dto.rws.RWSKioskTransactionDetailDTO["transactionMemberTypeDetail"]->sg.butterfly.emenu.api.dto.rws.RWSKioskTransactionMemberTypeDetailDTO["sPatronName"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:388)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1611)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:359)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2938)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
    ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x92
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 646]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:663)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidInitial(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidChar(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3535)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2481)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2407)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:36)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:104)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:357)
    ... 114 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you share your Dto `RWSKioskTransactionMemberTypeDetailDTO` please ? What is the type of `sPatronName` ?

Comment: Have you dumped the exact bytes of the request (including all headers and the body)? That's really crucial information. (Perhaps the request is compressed, for example?) I do find it interesting that it's "line 1, column 646" that is the problem - suggesting that it's managing to parse *some* of the JSON without problems. My *guess* is that even if the request *claims* it's UTF-8, it's actually not.

Comment: (Scratch the compression idea, btw - I hadn't spotted the "line 1, column 646" bit when I wrote that. It seems very likely that this is an encoding issue - but at the client, not the server.)

Comment: 0x92 is a comma-like single quote in Windows-1252 encoding (MS Latin-1), in line 1, position 625. Maybe a paste from Word text. Multi-byte sequences in UTF-8 have as start bytes 0xC0 - 0xFF. 0x92 would be a continuation byte of a sequence. That is what the error says.

Comment: @QuentinGenet, `sPatronName` is of type String

Comment: @JonSkeet, actually this issue is not happening for all the requests, only for subset of the requests, so, compression should not be the case I believe, if compression is happening, it should happen for all the requests

Comment: As noted in the third comment, I don't think it *is* compression. I strongly suspect that the client isn't encoding the data properly (as Joop Eggen says). But having the full request in a pristine format would make it easier to help you.